# Most Efficient Way to Create Pandas DataFrame from Web Scraped Data

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've web scraped some data via Python's Beautiful Soup library. There were numerous options on how to transform that data into a Pandas DataFrame and I was curious what would be the most efficient?

I ended up creating a dictionary for each item and adding each item to a list. Here was my code:

```
value_list = []

# iterate through all files
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".html"): 
        file = open(directory + "//" + filename)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(file)
        rank = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'rank'})
        value1 = soup.findAll('a', attrs={"class": "things"})
        value2 = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'blah'})
        value3 = soup.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'stuff'})
        
        for i in range(len(rank)):
            vaule_dict = {'Rank': int(rank[i].text.strip()), 
                           'V1': value1[i].text.strip(), 
                           'V2': value2[i].text.strip(), 
                           'V3': value3[i].text.strip()}
        
            value_list.append(value_dict)
            
df = pd.DataFrame(value_list)
```

Would there be a more efficient way to do this or is this methodology pretty sound?

Comment: couple thoughts: this may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python, and IIRC, `pandas` handles a lot of the optimization in creating the dataframe for the user - so, that seems like a perfectly sound method of getting to that point to me.

Comment: It really depends on the HTML, a very efficient approach is to use pandas directly with [`.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html?highlight=read_html#pandas-read-html) but you will probably then need to do some clean up on the resulting dataframe(s)