# What is the most efficient(fastest) way to create a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project that reads a couple of thousand text documents, creates a dataframe from them, and then trains a model on the dataframe. The most time-consuming aspect of the code is the creation of the dataframe.

Here is how I create the dataframe:

I first create 4-5 lists, create a dictionary with 'Column-name' as the key and the previous lists as the values. Then use `pd.DataFrame` to give the dictionary. I have added print updates after each step and the dataframe creation step takes the most time.

Method I am using:

```
line_of_interest = []
line_no = []
file_name = []
for file in file_names:
    with open(file) as txt:
        for i, line in enumerate(txt):
            if 'word of interest' in line:
                line_of_interest.append(line)
                line_no.append(i)
                file_name.append()

rows = {'Line_no':line_no,'Line':line_of_interest,'File':file_name}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = rows)
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient and less time-consuming way to create the dataframe. I tried looking for similar questions and the only thing I could find was ["Most Efficient Way to Create Pandas DataFrame from Web Scraped Data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55563796/most-efficient-way-to-create-pandas-dataframe-from-web-scraped-data).

Let me know if there is a similar question with a good answer. The only other method of creating a dataframe I know is appending row by row all the values as I discover them, and I don't know a way to check if that is quicker. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some code for reference to what you already have.

Comment: @PythonicOreo I have updated the question